# Firebase callable function blocked by CORS when arg passed in and returned, but is fine otherwise?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been struggling all day with one of my Firebase callable functions (not HTTP or onRequest function) being blocked by CORS policy when I try to call it from my Flutter app (this is Flutter web if that matters). I'm using the Firebase Functions 2nd-genration and in typescript. I finally tried to narrow down the root cause by writing 3 simple test functions as follows:

(firebase functions server - typescript code):

```
exports.testStupid = onCall(async function testStupid(): Promise<string> {
  return "hello world";
});

exports.testStupidWithArgs = onCall(async function testStupidWithArgs(request: CallableRequest): Promise<string> {
  const something = request.data;
  return `hello world and also ${something}`;
});

exports.testStupidWithUnusedArgs = onCall(async function testStupidWithUnusedArgs(request: CallableRequest): Promise<string> {
  const something = request.data;
  console.log(something);
  return "hello world";
});
```

And I'm calling it in Flutter as follows, in this case the 3rd of the 3 functions above:

```
      final FirebaseFunctions cloudFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
      final callableFunc =
          cloudFunctions.httpsCallable('testStupidWithUnusedArgs');
      final result = await callableFunc.call('testingArg here!!');
      print(result.data);
```

When I call the 1st function (testStupid) which doesn't take any arguments, it works and prints in the flutter console as expected.

When I call the 2nd function and pass in the string argument that is then used in the string returned by the function (`hello world and also ${something}`), I get the CORS error.

But interestingly, when I call the 3rd function, which also takes an argument but doesn't use it in the return value, it works and prints as expected. And when I view the firebase console log the argument was logged as expected too.

So what's going on? Why is the 2nd function not working? (I'm sure that it had been made public via "cloud functions invoker" and "cloud run invoker" for allUsers, etc. Somehow I don't think CORS is the actual problem as the other 2 functions have the exact same permissions but work fine.